# How do you use javascript to count number of rows in a "flat" table

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

Say I have the following table. How would I show the number of rows in the table using simple javascript within a paragraph `<p id="rowscount"></p>`.

I am new to javascript so it would be helpful if you can include any comments regarding how to call a function for example.

```html
<p id="rowscount"></p>


<table>

  <tr>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>Two</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>Two</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: _"any comments regarding how to call a function"_ Stack Overflow isn't really the place for covering such basics - there are plenty of tutorial websites and/or books (remember those!) around that cover this ground.

Comment: At the very least check out [codecademy](http://codecademy.com) and give their JavaScript course a go. It's free and will teach you the basics.

Comment: This works fine to count visible rows: `document.getElementById('rowscount').innerHTML = $('tr:visible').length-1`. However it does not update, do I need to put onChange somewhere in this statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have the table as following:

```
<div id="rowsNumber"></div>
<table id="myTable">

  <tr>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>Two</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>Two</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

In some browser the table data rows goes wrapped inside a tbody tag as following:

```
<div id="rowsNumber"></div>
<table id="myTable">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>One</td>
        <td>Two</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>One</td>
        <td>Two</td>
      </tr>
    <tbody>
    </table>
```

so define a function like this:

```
var getTableRowCount = function(tableNode){
  var tbody = tableNode.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
  if(tbody){
   return tbody.getElementsByTagName('tr').length;
  }else{
   return tableNode.getElementsByTagName('tr').length;
  }

}
```

And call the function passing the table node as parameter for example:

```
var count = getTableRowCount(document.getElementById('myTable'));
document.getElementById('rowsNumber').innerHTML = 'Total rows = ' + count;
```

Now if you want to observe a listener so that whenever any `tr` of the table  changes its visibility you need to have a `MutationObserver` observing on the tr rows. To add mutation observer you can write some code like this:

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
     var count = getTableRowCount(document.getElementById('myTable'));
     document.getElementById('rowsNumber').innerHTML = 'Total rows = '   + count;
  });

//find the target on which to observe
var target = document.querySelector('table tr');

observer.observe(target, {
    attributes: true
});
```

Comment: This works fine to count visible rows: document.getElementById('rowscount').innerHTML = $('tr:visible').length-1. However it does not update, do I need to put onChange somewhere in this statement?

Comment: Please check the updated answer. I added one MutationObserver so that whenever any changes occur you can recalculate the no. of rows

Answer (score 0):

please try bellow code

```js
var table = document.getElementById('myTable');
document.getElementById("rowscount").innerHTML = table.childNodes.length;
```

```html
<p id="rowscount"></p>
<table id="myTable">

  <tr>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>Two</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>Two</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: This works fine to count visible rows: document.getElementById('rowscount').innerHTML = $('tr:visible').length-1. However it does not update, do I need to put onChange somewhere in this statement?